BTZ black hole as a quotient of AdS space
I am trying to understand this paper 1 and trying to reproduce some calculations and had some questions about that. In section 3.2, page 12, eq. 3.9, the authors are writing normal geodesics of an arbitrary Mobius transformation in terms of the Eigenvalues and the fixed points. I do not understand how are they writing those normal geodesics. They start with an arbitrary transformation and diagonalize it:
\begin{equation}
    \gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \;\;,\;\;
    \gamma' = M^{-1} \gamma M = \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{\lambda} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \;\;,\;\;
    M = \begin{bmatrix}
    \zeta_A & \zeta_B \\
    1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}~.
\end{equation}
This makes sense. We write $\lambda$, $\zeta_A$, $\zeta_B$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, ,using the fact that $ad-bc = 1$, as
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}
   \lambda &= \frac{1}{2} \left( a+d + \sqrt{(a+d)^2 - 4} \right)\\
   \zeta_A &= \frac{ a-d + \sqrt{(a+d)^2 - 4}}{2 c} \\
   \zeta_B &= \frac{ a-d - \sqrt{(a+d)^2 - 4}}{2 c}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
Next, they write the normal geodesics in terms of $\lambda$, $\zeta_A$ and $\zeta_B$ as:
\begin{align}
    \left(x - \frac{\zeta_A r^2 - \zeta_B}{r^2 - 1}\right)^2 + y^2 &= \frac{(\zeta_A - \zeta_B)^2 r^2}{(r^2 - 1)^2} \\ \nonumber
    \left(x - \frac{\zeta_A \lambda^4 r^2 - \zeta_B}{\lambda^4 r^2 - 1}\right)^2 + y^2 &= \frac{(\zeta_A - \zeta_B)^2 \lambda^4 r^2}{(\lambda^4 r^2 - 1)^2}~.
\end{align}
I do not know how are they writing the center terms and the right-hand sides. How can I reproduce it?
Next. they write two arbitrary non-intersecting normal geodesics centered at $x_1$ and $x_2$ with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$. and start defining the endpoints $(u_1, v_1)$ for geodesic 1 and $(u_2, v_2)$ for geodesic 2 as:
\begin{gather}
    \text{Geodesic 1}\; : \quad u_1 = x_1 + r_1 \quad , \quad v_1 = x_1 - r_1 \nonumber \\
    \text{Geodesic 2} \; : \quad u_2 = x_2 + r_2 \quad , \quad v_2 = x_2 - r_2~.
\end{gather}
and then suddenly they write the horizon length without any explanation in equation 3.12 as:
\begin{equation}
    L_H = 2\ \ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{\left|(u_1 - u_2)(v_1 - v_2)\right|}{(u_1 - v_1)(u_2 - v_2)}}
    +
    \sqrt{\frac{\left|(u_1 - v_2)(v_1 - u_2)\right|}{(u_1 - v_1)(u_2 - v_2)}} \right)~.
\end{equation}
Please help me understand how is that the horizon length?
